# Socket Io misses connection events

Tags: flutter, dart, socket.io

I am testing my app, so I am purposely disconnecting from wifi and then connecting
eg. (Disconnect, Connect, Disconnect, Connect..)
and I realized that socket_io_client [pub.dev link here](https://pub.dev/packages/socket_io_client) doesn't fire any internal events (connect_error, disconnect... ) except for the first time I disconnect, I receive all the events (connect_error then disconnect etc.).

Do you have any idea where the problem might be?

Comment: Are you listening to the event stream?

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned, the first time I disconnect it works fine, and I receive those events, but the second, third .. it doesn't work. It doesn't make any sense.